# why when I use the sideBarView to be Toggled and presented the toolbar is hidden

Tags: toolbar, navigationview

I have this List of items, with a toolbar, when I use the geometryReader to show on the side the   sideBarCockpitView() the toolbar disappears?

var body: some View {

```
    ZStack{
        
        List(itemData.items) { item in
            Button(action: {
                if let index = itemData.items.firstIndex(of: item) {
                    itemData.items[index].isSelected.toggle()
                    saveData(itemData: itemData)
                }
                
            }) {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text(item.name)
                        .foregroundColor(textColor(for: item))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10) // Adjust the vertical padding here
                    
                    if item.name == "ATIS & TOPA (NOTAM?)" {
                        TextField("TOPA RWY:", text: $TOPAText)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                            .autocapitalization(.allCharacters)
                    }
                    if item.name == "RCL - TECH & CAB LOG\n         - DAILY Check" {
                        
                        Button {
                            showMELview.toggle()
                            
                        } label: {
                            Text("MEL")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .padding(10)
                                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showMELview) {
                            MELItems()
                        }.padding(10)
                    }
                    if item.name == "FMS & QR" {
                        Button {
                            showOFPPersonalNotesview.toggle()
                            
                        } label: {
                            Text("OFP notes")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .padding(10)
                                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showOFPPersonalNotesview) {
                            sideOFPpersonalNotes()
                        }.padding(5)
                    }
                    
                    if item.name == "PA" {
                        Button {
                            welcomePASheetPresented.toggle()
                            
                        } label: {
                            Text("PA")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .padding(10)
                                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                        }.padding(5)
                    }
                    
                    
                    if item.name == "BRIEF — CLX-DCL | CL" {
                        Button {
                            showDepBriefView.toggle()
                            
                        } label: {
                            Text("DepBrief")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .padding(10)
                                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showDepBriefView) {
                            DEPbriefView()
                        }.padding(5)
                    }
                    if item.name == "FMS/NSS, FLT OPS/ OANS" {
                        TextField("AIRAC", text: $Airac)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .frame(width: 60)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 2)
                            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                            .autocapitalization(.allCharacters)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    if item.name == "FMS/NSS, FLT OPS/ OANS" {
                        TextField("ERM", text: $ERM)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 60)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding(.horizontal, 2)
                            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                            .autocapitalization(.allCharacters)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    if item.name == "L/S—XcheckAV — Accept L/S" {
                        TextField("OFP", text: $OFPnbr)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .frame(width: 50)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding(.horizontal, 2)
                            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                            .autocapitalization(.allCharacters)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    
                }
                
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .stroke(item.isSelected ? Color.clear : Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                        .background(item.isSelected ? Color.black : Color.clear).cornerRadius(10)
                ).padding(.vertical, 0)
            }.listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        
        .toolbar {
            HStack{
                
                Text("T - \(TminusSTD)")
                    .frame(width: 100)
                    .padding(5)
                //  .cornerRadius(5)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .background(timeBackground())
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                ///
                Spacer()
                if let topaTowDouble = Double(TOPAtow) {
                    let formattedValue = String(format: "FLX TOW %.1f T", topaTowDouble)
                    
                    if topaTowDouble != 0 {
                        Text(formattedValue)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding(5)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                    } else {
                        Text(formattedValue)
                            .hidden()
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle the case where TOPAtow is not a valid Double
                    Text("")
                }
                
                
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    resetItemsToInitialState()
                }) {
                    Text("Reset")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(8)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
     
        
        GeometryReader { _ in // when I use this the toolbar dissapears
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                sideBarCockpitView()
                
            }
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
        updateSkedTime()
        if !timerStopped {
            updateUTCLabel()
            updateIntervalText()
            saveToUserDefaults()
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: depTime) {
        timerStopped = false
        TminusSTD = "00:00:00"
        saveToUserDefaults()
    }
    ///
    .onAppear {
        restoreData(itemData: itemData)
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        ///
        flightTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "flightTime") as? Date ?? Date()
        arrTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "arrTime") as? Date ?? Date()
        depTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "depTime") as? Date ?? Date()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(TminusSTD, forKey: "intervalText")
        ///
        
    }
    .onDisappear {
        saveToUserDefaults() // para el timer
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $welcomePASheetPresented) {
        WelcomePAviewPDF(pdfName: "PA1")
    }
    
}
```

What I expect is to show the list of items, the toolbar in the upper side, and a sideBar.
The sidebar has a button that offsets the View and it should shows over the list without affecting the visibility of the toolbar.
The app starts with a List menu that shows different options, when press in one you go to a detail view with a navigationLink, which is the one presented here.